# How to add the current date and time to the name of a saved file?

Tags: javascript, java, android, datetime, android-activity

I am working on [this sound recorder](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/media/mediarecorder/android-audio-capture-example/#viewSource) activity. I added a restart button to an activity to start recording again, but the problem with the code is it overwrites the new record file over the last file. I want to edit this part of the code.

```
outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().
    getAbsolutePath() + "/Recording" + date + time + ".3gpp";
```

The problem is, I am a noob at coding and I don't know how to explain date and time and I don't know if it works or not.

Comment: Change `date + time`  to `(date.getTime()+Math.random())` to get a unique name - as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20120562/javascript-timestamp-number-is-not-unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks a lot my friends.but i found the answer myself.
add:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
```

then add:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
int seconds = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
int minutes = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
int date = cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

and then:

```
outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().
       getAbsolutePath() + "/Recording" + (year) + "-" + (month) + "-" + (date) + "-" + (hour) + "-" + (minutes) + "-" + (seconds) + ".3gpp";
```

its worked for me.

Comment: Another way to skin a cat (but more verbose and error prone)

Answer (score 1):

How about something like

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    String fName = String.format ("myFile_%s.txt", sdf.format(new Date ()));
```

And thanks to @FabianGünter for making this a complete solution with

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss"); 
outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(). 
             getAbsolutePath() + "/Recording" + sdf.format(new Date()) + ".3gpp";
```

Comment: I'll hack this answer to provide a full code example according to the code you gave:

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().
    getAbsolutePath() + "/Recording" + sdf.format(new Date()) + ".3gpp";

Comment: @FabianGünter Thanks I have edited my answer with your input.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a unique name you could use .

You'd use it to replace date and time. getAbsolutePath() + "/Recording" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".3gpp";

It gives the number of milliseconds since January 1st 1970. Which is generally going to be a uid. And will certainly create unique and sequential names.

Answer (score 0):

Use This function it will return you a unique file path with date and time

```
public String getUniqueFilePath(String name,String formate) {
    photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HHmmss",
                    Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date()) + name + formate);
    return photo.getPath();
}
```